# How can I display several images from within a for loop

Tags: java, image, for-loop

For school I need to make a game dealing [X] random cards.
I used this code to buildup and display my images.
There is only one thing going wrong. When displaying the project, only the last card is 
displayed.

Is there any way I can show these images next to each other?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Cards cards = new Cards();
    int dealSize = 6;
    deal = cards.getShuffledCards(dealSize);
    System.out.println("Deal of 4 randomly picked cards " + deal);
    f = new JFrame();
    for(int i=0; i < dealSize; i++) {
        card = deal.get(i).toString();
        f.getContentPane().add(setLabel(card));
    }
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);



}

public static JLabel setLabel(String fileLocation) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream([DIRECTORY TO IMAGES]" + fileLocation));
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        return label;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably have to make an arbitrary grid, in which one card can occupy each part. Like a GridLayout or GridBagLayout.

From what I can see by skimming your code, you are basically overwriting the last element you put, for each iteration.

Comment: That is what i was scared for too. But I realy don't know how I can dynamicly add images

Comment: As I said, try a different layout. Like a GridLayout. If you are allowed to, you can easily set it up in a GUI builder like NetBeans.